# How do I free up space on iCloud when I have already deleted many photos and turned off iCloud photos but not "my photo stream"?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

How do I free up space on iCloud when I have already deleted many photos and turned off iCloud photos but not "my photo stream"?

I want to be able to back up my iPhone with the iCloud but there are so many pictures taking up space in iCloud it won't back up now.

I have already downloaded all my cell phone pics to my computer; So I don't need the iCloud to back up pictures.

Please help.

Comment: If this is question as I understand, I would edit title to: How to exclude Photos from iCloud backup in iOS to save iCloud space

Answer (score 1):

To remove Photos (Photo Library) from iCloud backup:

- Please open Settings/ your name iCloud
- Open Storage/Manage Storage
- Open Backups (iOS12) / select the backup for your iPhone
- Switch off the Photo Library - this will exclude the Photo Library from the backup (you can do it while backup in progress)
- Tap Turn Off & Delete (if already exists)

Answer (score -1):

Pay for a larger iCloud storage tier.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201238

$2.99 per month gets you 200GB of free space in iCloud. This should be more than enough space to back up your photos and other items.

It's worth it to pay a small amount of money for another form of off-site backup.